# How to use Cucumber and Factory Girl together?

Tags: cucumber, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm trying to configure FactoryGirl to work with my Cucumber tests.
I added the following lines in env.rb

```
require 'factory_girl'
Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../spec/factories/*.rb')).each {|f| require f }
```

When I run 'cucumber features', there's no problem.
I now add a file called `teacher.rb` to `spec/factories` and add the following in:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :teacher do
    first_name "John"
    last_name "Smith"
  end
end
```

Now when I run `cucumber features` I get:
`uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)`

I'm obviously missing something, but what is it? How do I get Cucumber to work with Factory Girl?

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to follow documentation for an unreleased version of Factory Girl. Take a look at the docs for the most recent version here:

http://rdoc.info/gems/factory_girl/1.3.3/frames

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have these steps covered. They worked for me flawlessly.

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2010/09/09/practical-cucumber-factory-girl-steps/

Mainly you have to require "factory_girl/step_definitions"

Comment: Old integration is now deprecated, read this article for more information.
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-better-cucumber-scenarios-or-why-were

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going to repeat what Dan Croak said, as it can be incredibly frustrating.  (Even the factory_girl_rails plugin points to the wrong file.)  You need to follow the syntax here, instead:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/1.3.x

Thanks Dan!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with cucumber in rails4. Running `rake cucumber features` instead of just `cucumber features` solved the problem.